# Group elements by a changing attribute

Tags: xquery

I am trying to group elements via changing attributes, this could be easily done with XQuery 3.0 Tumbling Windows, but I'm limited to XQuery 1.0.

The input looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <value attr="a" no="1"/>
    <value attr="a" no="2"/>
    <value attr="b"/>
    <value attr="a" no="3"/>
    <value attr="b"/>
    <value attr="b"/>
    <value attr="a" no="4"/>
    <value attr="a" no="5"/>
    <value attr="b"/>
    <value attr="a" no="6"/> 
</root>
```

The required output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="1"/>
        <value attr="a" no="2"/>
    </new>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="3"/>
    </new>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="4"/>
        <value attr="a" no="5"/>
    </new>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="6"/>
    </new>
</root>
```

My first attempt was the following, which does not return the expected result because of the way nested for-loops work in XQuery 1.0

```
<root>{
for $changeNode in doc("Untitled4.xml")//root/value
where $changeNode[@attr="a" and preceding::value[@attr!="a"]]
return
<new>{
            for $sameNode in  $changeNode/following::value
            where $sameNode[@attr="a"]
            return $sameNode
            }</new>
}</root>
```

It results in:

```
<root>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="4"/>
        <value attr="a" no="5"/>
        <value attr="a" no="6"/>
    </new>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="5"/>
        <value attr="a" no="6"/>
    </new>
    <new>
        <value attr="a" no="6"/>
    </new>
    <new/>
</root>
```

Comment: Why did you delete your first question? This is a quite annoying behavior and not welcome on SO, as answer are also here to help others! Why didn't you simply amend that you are limited to 1.0, I would have edited my answer accordingly (as would have others)? Simply deleting your question and asking the some one once again is not very constructive.

Comment: Also, as you claimed you in the old (now deleted) question you found a solution, I wonder why you even ask?!

Comment: I've no solution. I forgot to make the restriction to "XQuery 1.0".

Comment: That's why I am saying that you could have simply edited your original question. This way, my answer is simply deleted, which frankly is quite annoying as you certainly can understand that it takes me time to actually write answers and it could have helped others. It would not have been a problem to also provide an answer for XQuery 1.0, but as you simply delete questions with their answer, I am unwilling to invest even more time.

Comment: In short: As you are new to SO, please make yourself familiar with how SO works in the help section. This is crucial to actually get answer.

Comment: Of course you are right, next time I know what to do (and what not). P.S. I guess voting down my question isn't correct only because I deleted the old one ;)

Comment: That's correct, but that's not the sole reason why I downvoted (btw, voting is anonymous, so this could also have been from someone else - In this case it isn't). I consider the question as it stands as "not useful", partly because I fear you delete the question again, which is not useful by definition. But also, because the title is incorrect (referring to XQuery 1.0 or XQuery 3.0 does not belong in the title), your tags are incorrect and most importantly you do not show what you already tried yourself.

Comment: Better now? Some concrete advices would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is the cleanest solution but this should work: Select the starting nodes for each group, then select all following nodes and eliminate the ones that should not be in this group:

```
for $start in //value[(not(preceding::value) or preceding::value[1]/@attr != @attr) and @attr = 'a']
return 
  <new>{
    for $item in ($start, $start/following::value[@attr = $start/@attr]) except ($start/following::value[@attr !=  $start/@attr]/following::value )
      return $item
  }</new>
```

edit: just noticed that you only want the 'a' entries

Comment: Thanks, it just works. I would love to upvote, but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: you should be able to accept the answer though :P (i think)